# Javascript click to open and close menu, NOT using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, html-lists

I want to have a menu, that I can click on to open, and click on to close.
Similar to a hover menu, but with clicking, to open, and clicking to close.
I have three visible list items, with submenu's under.

These are hidden with css, display:none.
I can get them to show, with the keyword "this", and a for loop for checking if any 'ul', have more then 1 item, then list will open when clicked.

As far as I could understand this code, I got some help here earlier.
Now I have read, and watched tutorials from buckysroom, and feel I understand a lot more, at least about arrays, and everything in the code, I can  now understand, at least. I have this code at the moment.

```
function showMenu(parentElement){
    var uls= parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    if (uls.length > 0)
        uls[0].setAttribute("style","display: block");

 }

function load(){ 
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            showMenu(this);
        }); 
    }
}
```

As I understood, finally, the 'for' loop, I see that this code opens any array, or like, any 'li' that has more than 1 ( [0] ) item, as 0 is 1 in array, and loops through to see if it has children. If it does, it opens 'this' 'li's'  'ul'.

Since the load function, contains the showMenu function, and I have learned a little, to use functions inside functions, rather than copy myself, use arrays and variables, and assign them to eachother somehow. Buckysroom tutorials, at least helped me understand as much.

Now..
My problem is I do not know enough Javascript to get my mind around this, and I would rather not use jQuery, but learn how this could be achieved with plain Javascript.

Any pointers would help alot, I have tried the following;

Adding unique Id's to my three ul's, so I know can in fact open them with the above code, and I am able to close them, with another code, setting it back to "display:none".

The problem then, is I do not have the opportunity to open them again, and I understand that I am missing some piece, like stopPropagation or maybe, using addEventListener - Click, for this second part. As you may understand, the addeventListener, is something I got from a code in here.

```
 function Meny1(){

    var unorderedList = document.getElementById("ul_1");

            var lis = unorderedList.getElementsByTagName("li");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","display: none");

            }
}
```

I figured out, that I can specify each menu-item with numbers, like [23], instead of [i], to target a single menu item, copy that line like this:

```
lis[23].setAttribute("style","display: none");
lis[24].setAttribute("style","display: none");
```

But as I understand, that is a bad practice, as it is terrible if I am to add another menu item, or remove one, and also is way to much copy-coding..

My thought, is that I want something like this:
html:

```
<div id ="cssmenu"></div>
<ul id="ul_1"><li>I have many li's in each 'ul'</li></ul>
<ul id="ul_2"><li>I have many li's in each 'ul'</li></ul>
<ul id="ul_3"><li>I have many li's in each 'ul'</li></ul>
```

css:

```
#cssmenu{display:block;}
#cssmenu ul li ul{display:none}
```

My thinking of how the js should be, and I DON'T use CLASSES:
(I didn't do this, as w3c validator pointed out that I shouldn't).

```
function showAndCloseMenu1(){
var ul_1 = document.getElementbyId("ul_1");
    if(mouseclicked on ul_2 || mouseclicked on ul_3){
        close.ul_1(this)
    }
        if(mouseClicked ul_1){
         style.display = "block";
        }
}
```

And then the same naturally for ul_2 and ul_3, I have not gotten good enough yet to think about implementing all into one code, but I know that it is possible of course, with global variables, and by using attributes.

Is there Anyone who can help me with this?

I have tried to use jQuery, with no success, and as I said, would rather not, as I am eager to learn Javascript to the fullest extend! And I can read Javascript, jQuery is just a bunch of dollarsigns to me, with simplified Javascript inside.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ufcsccy3/

Here is a fiddle, but the menu doesn't work as it does in browsers, but you get the idea if you look there, its the menu on the left.

How can I have a show/hide function, in my navigation with Javascript?
Am I thinking in the correct path here, as I see it, classes makes little difference, but maybe saves me some coding space thou.

Thanks for any help whatsoever on this, cannot seem to get my head around a working solution for this!
I would like to have it like when I click on ul_1 first time, it opens. If I click it again, I want it to close.
If ul_1 is open, and I click ul_2, or ul_3, I want to open that one, and close ul_1 again, kinda standard menu navigation in my perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just toggle an ID for the open menu. One method, `onclick`, which does it all.

```js
function showmenu(elem) {
  // Clear any currently open menu
  var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");
  if (openMenu) {
    openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
    // Stop if we're just closing the current menu
    if (openMenu === elem) {
      return;
    }
  }

  // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
  // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
  if (elem.getElementsByTagName("li").length > 0) {
    elem.setAttribute("id", "activeMenu");
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#activeMenu ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="showmenu(this)">Menu Item 1</li>
  <li onclick="showmenu(this)">Drop Down 1
    <ul>
      <li>DD1 Item 1</li>
      <li>DD1 Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showmenu(this)">Drop Down 2
    <ul>
      <li>DD2 Item 1</li>
      <li>DD2 Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I used `onclick` just for simplicity. Adding the click event you did is the right way.

Comment: Seem to kind of work, but I have a funky problem, my menu loses all it's styling :o I have already assigned #cssmenu ul etc, in my css.
And tried to change activeMenu in the js, to cssmenu, no luck. Would I have to style all my css, like, cssmenu, AND copy all that style over to 
#activeMenu? So double up the css kindof, for the menu?

Seemed a working code, and very good explained, very appreciated :)

Comment: Are you using an ID on each individual LI element already? Or do you just have one on the actual menu? If there's nothing on the LIs to begin with, you should just be able to add the `#activeMenu` to the CSS, and everything stay the same.

Comment: Note, I also changed the first showmenu, to showMenu, so should be the css right?
@David

Comment: I see, I only have unique ID for the nav element, no id's for the lis. The <a tag, have onclicks, should I remove the load function from body, and only use the code you supplied?

Comment: Don't use the onclicks, see the last line of my post. The way you did it in the `load` method is better, though you may want to only add it to direct child elements. Names are irrelevant, as long as everything matches. If the styles are still being cleared, use the debugger tool to see what is overwritting them. `#activeMenu` should serve only to make its child `ul` visible. Other styles should come from their original location.

Comment: Ok, but it will work with onclick? Only try to get it working firstly, since I do not feel save at changing ur code, before I know it works :) Cannot have any id's inside the cssmenu? I have some buttons there with id I noticed

Comment: Yes, but then it will fire twice. If you're keeping the `onclick` for now, then remove the `load` function. You can have IDs inside, but if what is being assigned `#activeMenu` already has an ID, then the previous ID will be cleared. You may need to use a class for the other stuff if that's the case.

Comment: changed all me #cssmenu, to .cssmenu, and it worked:) Lost alot of my styling on top elements thou, but that I can figure out:)
But'uhm, is all the submenus supposed to open?
I open menuItem 1, and submenuItem1, submenu,2 and everyone is open, not just first three-branch :O Hm, should use array-method for solving that?
ul_1 open every sub, ul_2 and ul_3 stay closed thou, so minor issue, thanks alot :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69661/discussion-between-david-and-sunto).

Comment: found the conflicting item know also, 
.cssmenu ul li ul {
 display:none;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 598;
 width: 100%;
}
This works,
#cssmenu ul li ul {
 display:none;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 598;
 width: 100%;
}
This did not :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function showMenu(elem) {
      // Clear any currently open menu
      var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");
  if (openMenu) {
        openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
        // Stop if we're just closing the current menu
        if (openMenu === elem) {
          return;
    }
  }

      // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
      // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
      if (elem.getElementsByTagName("ul").length > 0) {
        elem.setAttribute("id", "activeMenu");
      }
    }

        function showSubMenu(elem) {
      // Clear any currently open menu
          var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");
      if (openMenu)
        openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
      var openSubMenu = document.getElementById("activeSubMenu");
      if (openSubMenu) {
        openSubMenu.removeAttribute("id");
        // Stop if we're just closing the current menu

      }

      // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
      // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
      if (elem.getElementsByTagName("ul").length > 0) {
        elem.setAttribute("id", "activeSubMenu");
      }
    }
        function showLastSubMenu(elem) {
      // Clear any currently open menu
          var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");
      if (openMenu)
        openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
      var openSubMenu = document.getElementById("activeSubMenu");
      if (openSubMenu) 
        openSubMenu.removeAttribute("id");
        // Stop if we're just closing the current menu
    var openLastSubMenu = document.getElementById("activeSubMenu");
      if (openLastSubMenu) {
        openLastSubMenu.removeAttribute("id");

}
      // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
      // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
      if (elem.getElementsByTagName("ul").length > 0) {
        elem.setAttribute("id", "activeLastSubMenu");
      }
    }
```

I post the full code, that with much help from @David resultet in a clickable menu solution, Thanks alot :)

the css items #someMenu ul, #somemenu ul li, and #someMenu ul ul had to be changed to classes, so .someMenu ul etc.
    #activeMenu > ul {
      display: block;
    }

```
#activeSubMenu > ul {
  display: block;
}
#activeLastSubMenu > ul {

  display: block;
}
```

And in the html,

```
<nav id ="someMenu" class="someMenu">
function showMenu on the first level li's, 
function showSubMenu for next level
function showLastSubMenu for the last sub's (I had max 3 levels)
```

Alot of repeating, so I will try and make it into less code, with array and addEventListener, as you stated in you answer that is more correct!