# Open/Close menu On click using only javascript no jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my html file

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class ="mvbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href ="m">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href ="m">About</a></li>
            <li class="pjlist" onclick="load"><a href ="m">Projects</a>
                <div class="sub1">
                <ul>
                    <div class="arrow1"></div>
                    <li><a href ="m">Projects1</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Projects2</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Projects3</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="svlist" onclick="load"><a href ="m">Services</a>
                <div class="sub2">
                <ul>
                    <div class="arrow2"></div>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services1</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services2</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services3</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services4</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services5</a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href ="m">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and this is my css class

```
.mvbar ul {
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

.mvbar li {
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:grey;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    position:relative;
}

.mvbar li ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
}

.mvbar li ul li{
    float:none;
    width:210%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:4px;

}


.mvbar a {
    font-family:'Meiryo UI',Verdana,sans-serif;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}

.arrow1 {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:12px solid transparent;
    border-right:12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:12px solid grey;
    position:relative;
    right:-80%;
}

.arrow2 {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:12px solid transparent;
    border-right:12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:12px solid grey;
    position:relative;
    right:-80%;
}

.sub1 {
    visibility:hidden;
}

.sub2 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

I can do the same thing in css but requires many exceptions to be added so as to work in each and every browser but javascript is something that I haven't used before and I was suggested that it can be fairly easy to do with it.
So please can someone tell me how to open/close the sub-menu using only javascript.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well, you need to update lot many things. I have added some for you - http://plnkr.co/edit/V50U7sFYOX0hlxr9Y6U2?p=preview

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet just bits of code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167327/javascript-click-to-open-and-close-menu-not-using-jquery . But i can't figure what's the problem

Comment: @angry - have you tested the plunker?

Comment: @nikhil just one thing is it possible to add both onclick as well as on hover becoz when I am enabling on hover from css, on click disable and only on hover works

Comment: Yes. You can use onmouseover and onmouseout events/attributes

Comment: @nikhil ohk I'll try that and If I face any problems I'll disturb you again Thanks

Comment: @nikhil http://plnkr.co/edit/t9JWk3TfBhEG2UquavyA?p=preview can u modify it to add the onclick i am not able to achieve it

Comment: onclick on elements with class pjlist and svlist will not work as both have an anchor with an href. So, when you click on services and projects, the href associated with anchor is triggered and hence onclick on li does not fire.

Comment: @nikhil so u r saying that just removing the anchor wud do the trick ? or if theres anything else can u give me the possible code -_- that wud be awesome

Comment: Yes. Remove anchor and add onclick function

Comment: I got it man !! u rocked it thanx :-) thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work on 'hover' event not on 'click' but full css.

```
.mvbar ul {
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

.mvbar li {
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:grey;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    position:relative;
}

.mvbar li ul{
    position:absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.mvbar li ul li{
    float:none;
    width:210%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:4px;

}


.mvbar a {
    font-family:'Meiryo UI',Verdana,sans-serif;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}

.arrow2,
.arrow1 {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:12px solid transparent;
    border-right:12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:12px solid grey;
    position:relative;
    right:-80%;
}

.sub1,
.sub2
{
    visibility:hidden;
}


ul li:hover div
{
    visibility: visible;
}

ul li:hover ul
{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: As I wrote I can do on hover what i need is both on hover as well as on click !!! still Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
    .mvbar ul {
       list-style:none;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
    }

    .mvbar li {
        float:left;
        width:15%;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:grey;
        border-right:1px solid white;
        position:relative;
    }

    .mvbar li ul{
        position:absolute;
        top: 100%;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .mvbar li ul li{
        float:none;
        width:210%;
        text-align:left;
        padding-left:4px;

    }


    .mvbar a {
        font-family:'Meiryo UI',Verdana,sans-serif;
        color:black;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:block;
    }

    .arrow2,
    .arrow1 {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-left:12px solid transparent;
        border-right:12px solid transparent;
        border-bottom:12px solid grey;
        position:relative;
        right:-80%;
    }

    .sub1,
    .sub2
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

</style>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class ="mvbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href ="m">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">About</a></li>
            <li id="pjlist"><a href ="#">Projects</a>
                <div class="sub1">
                    <ul>
                        <div class="arrow1"></div>
                        <li><a href ="m">Projects1</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="m">Projects2</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="m">Projects3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="svlist" onclick="load"><a href ="m">Services</a>
                <div class="sub2">
                <ul>
                    <div class="arrow2"></div>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services1</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services2</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services3</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services4</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="m">Services5</a></li>
                </ul></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href ="m">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    var myMenu = document.getElementById("pjlist");
    var open = false;
    myMenu.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        if(open)
        {
            //then close
            open = !open;
            var mySubMenu = myMenu.getElementsByTagName('div');
            mySubMenu[0].style.visibility =  'hidden';
        }
        else
        {
            //open
            open = !open;
            var mySubMenu = myMenu.getElementsByTagName('div');
            mySubMenu[0].style.visibility =  'visible';
        }
    });

</script>
```

You can use

```
    var myMenus = document.getElementsByClassName()
```

to add the event listner on all your menu children.

Good Luck

Comment: sorry for late comment. Thanks !! would try it and surely tell the result :-)